# Gvim installation on vim-7.4

Tags: vim, linux-mint

I want vim-gtk to use vim 7.4 which I installed from source, but gvim is opening with 7.3 itself.

On A fresh linuxmint, after updating system, I removed already existing vim, than installed vim 7.4 from source and it is perfect installation, everything went fine, and than installed ,

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

than when I enter gvim, gvim is 7.3 not already existing 7.4!!! and if I enter vim from terminal than its vim-7.4.

I will be thankful if anyone helped me to run gvim on vim 7.4

Answer (score 3):

Two things…

First, `$ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk` only uses your repositories (which are certainly frozen at 7.3.something), it doesn't care at all about what you installed manually.

Second, GVim is *not* a separate frontend that you add to an existing Vim: it *is* Vim, built with GUI support and either launched as `gvim` or as `vim -g`.

You could:

- uninstall `vim-gtk` and re-compile Vim manually following [these instructions](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) (note the `--enable-gui=gtk2`)
- or find an up-to-date `ppa` on [LaunchPad.net](https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=vim), add it to your software sources and redo `$ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`.

Comment: No use of command - ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --enable-gui=gtk2  , make, make install.  even though all compilation runs without errors

Comment: Check the output of `./configure`. And paste it somewhere online so that we can read it.

Comment: You probably need to install a few development libraries before you can compile a GUI-enabled Vim. So before you do you ./configure command, try doing `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk` which should get everything you need to build.

Comment: ./configure  --enable-X11 --enable-xfontset --enable-xim --enable-xsmp --enable-xterm_clipboard --enable-xterm_save --enable-xpm --enable-gui=auto --with-tlib=ncurses --enable-multibyte --enable-clipboard --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3 --with-features=huge

Comment: configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-X11, --enable-xfontset, --enable-xterm_clipboard, --enable-xterm_save, --enable-xpm, --enable-clipboard, --enable-python3

Comment: Where do you get the source from? All those options are *very* basic.

Answer (score 1):

just install **vim-gnome** and **vim-gui** and reboot.It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this post](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-vim-7-4-on-debian-based-systems-from-source/) will help you install gvim 7.4. There are few steps:

- *Install the needed dependencies:*

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev build-essential mercurial
  ```
- *Clone the sources of Vim 7.4:*

  ```
  $ hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
  ```
- *Build Vim from sources:*

  ```
  $ cd vim/src
  $ make distclean
  $ ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --enable-rubyinterp
  $ make
  $ sudo make install
  ```
- Adjust the PATH:

  ```
  $ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  ```

I used this guide and get gvim 7.4.54.